# Absorption of element in a ring satisfying $[x, y]^3=[x, y]$ for all $x, y \in R$ where $[x, y]:=xy-yx$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The Theorem 17 from the paper [Variation on a Theme: Rings satisfying $x^3=x$ is commutative](http://archive.maths.nuim.ie/staff/sbuckley/Papers/bm_variations.pdf) by Stephen M. Buckley and Desmond MacHale says that "A ring $R$ is commutative if and only if $[x, y]^3=[x, y]$ for all $x, y \in R$ where $[x, y]:=xy-yx$."

I get stuck with a statement in the proof of this theorem. 
"Moreover, $[c', c'\pm d']=\pm[c', d']$ and $[d', c'\pm d']=-[c', d'].$
So, $(c'\pm d')^2$ is absorbed by $[c' , d']=[c, d]$ in the same way as $(c')^2$ and $(d')^2$ were." I don't know what does "is absorbed" here really mean.
I tried $(c'\pm d')^2+[c' , d']=[c' , d']$ and $(c'\pm d')^2[c' , d']=[c' , d']$, but they are not true.

Thank you in advance.